# Paypal SDK Mobile - IPN Listner?

Tags: paypal, payment

In the new paypal mobile SDK, there is no longer an IPN Listner. The payement verification is instant. But what if the payment fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [Verify a Mobile Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/) you will receive the status of the payment itself. IPN or IPN-like functionality should be coming with future releases as soon as that type of feature is supported with the underlying RESTful APIs. Unfortunately I do not have any eta on this particular implementation.